# Texturing a gas giant / moving noise

Tags: texturing

**context**

For practice with noise in blender I would like to create a scene as similar as I can to the one found in [this video](https://youtu.be/ldt6cBA2gmY). The hardest part is to create a texture similar to the one displayed on the planet. I would like some help trying to derive how the texture is built up.

As a start I found [this tutorial](http://gappyfacets.com/2016/08/05/blender-tutorial-make-flow-patterns-musgrave-texture/) that shows similar textures being made by the use of noise, but the results are much simpler. I was wondering if the noise textures used in this video could be combined one texture.

My first question is wether this texture could have been generated using noise or if it has been made using an a fluid simulation (or both). The flow of the texture on lower levels looks very realistic, altough the higher levels of the texture look generated using noise.

**Texture layers**

The finest details of the texture seem to me like the combination of musgrave noise with very small scaled wave noise at its input, but more 'feathery', like the musgrave noise combined with white noise. Is there any combination of these two types of noise that result in a similar pattern?

This generated noise seems to be stretched out and compressed by a moving fluid-like animation. If the lines of the wave noise get closer, the detail between them and they combine into a feathery blur. I have no Idea how I would accomplish a similar effect in blender. Any help with this would be appreciated.

On top of all layers there seems to be a moving combination of musgrave noise and wave noise as a "filter" to change the colour (gradient) of the lower noise on a larger scale. The wave noise seems to have a large scale and the filter must have very gentle colour gradient.

**Well formulated questions**

Could a similar texture be created using just noise generation from blender?

How do I combine the types of noise as shown in the tutorial into the "feathery waves"?

How could I achieve a similar flowing movement in the noise?

Did I miss any effects from the video in my layer breakdown?

Comment: You'll probably need layers of noise texture all with different amounts of detail. Then their vectors will be driven by other animated nose textures to get the boiling effect.

Comment: Sorry if this isn't helpful, but Houdini has some amazing Mandelbulb solvers if that interests you lol

Answer (score 2):

Texture coordinates are an array of three values for X,Y and Z.

Colour is an array of three (or four with alpha) values for R,G and B.

While we are taught to only connect matching sockets in a node tree, some differing sockets are interchangeable, colour and vector are one of these interchangeable types.

What this means is that we can connect a noise texture and texture coordinates into a mixRGB node and then connect that to the vector input of another node. This distorts the texture coordinates in a way that can give results like what you are after. You can then add another mixRGB to combine a second texture, and third...

[image: a gas planet]

The [SpaceVFX tutorial](https://gumroad.com/l/spaceVFX) explains this in more detail, including using it to also make solid planets by defining water and land then add some mountains and rivers to the land.